# Changing Individual Characters of a Character Array in C

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this Seg Fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638851/why-does-this-seg-fault)

Hello, I have a

```
char* str = "blah";
```

And I now want to change one of the characters to something else, say a number 3. I am trying to do so with:

```
str[2] = '3';
```

However I am getting a seg fault at this line of code. Any idea why?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638851/why-does-this-seg-fault).

Answer (score 3):

That's not an array of chars. It's a pointer to char initialized with a string constant. String constants cannot be modified, but if you make it an array of chars rather than a char pointer, it will work. e.g.

```
char str[] = "blah";
str[2] = '3';
```

Comment: While this was helpful in finding my way to the solution, the link to the duplicate question explained WHY I was running into the issue, and therefore I selected it as the best answer. Nonetheless, I appreciate the help, and up voted your response.