# Bus error when using memmove

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error, bus, memmove

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bus error troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458854/bus-error-troubleshooting)

To remove duplicates from a string this is the program I have written:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void remDup(char str[])
{
    int i=0,len;
int arr[256]={[0 ... 255] = 0};

while(str[i]!='\0')
{   
    len=strlen(str);
    if(arr[str[i]]==1)
    {
        memmove(str+i,str+i+1,len);
    }
    else
        arr[str[i]]=1;
    i++;
}

printf("String with Unique Characters:%s\n",str);

}

main()
{
remDup("kjijhgfedcaba");
}
```

But the error displayed on running the program is:
Bus error: 10

What changes have to made in the code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but I'd also suggest you try to find a less heavy-handed algorithm.  This one is very costly.

Comment: @fvu May I know why this is heavy-handed?(I am new to coding)

Comment: Actually the question was to do it in O(1) space and O(n) time complexity

Comment: On each iteration you do a strlen and potentially a memmove, whereas a loop over the individual characters of the string would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"kjijhgfedcaba"` is a string literal and you cannot modify a string literal in C.

By the way if you want to initialize all the `arr` elements to `0`, instead of this (which is a GNU extension):

```
int arr[256]={[0 ... 255] = 0};
```

you can simply do this:

```
int arr[256]= {0};
```

Comment: +1, didn't look at the invocation. Shouldn't it complain at compile time?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker no, modifying a string literal is undefined behavior and C does not require a diagnostic when you invoke undefined behavior. But the compiler would be free to do it if it notices.

Comment: I meant when passing string literal as non-const char array? Plain c does have a concept of `const`, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker for historical reasons string literals are of type `char [N]` and not `const char [N]` so the diagnostic is not required at the function call.

Comment: ah. This is only true for plain c?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker This is different in C++, in C++ the type of string literals is `const char [N]` so the compiler has to issue a diagnostic.

Comment: @Michael Krelin Thank you. Its working after making this change in the main function: char a[]={"kjijhgfedcaba"};
        remDup(a);

Comment: @MaheshOstwal, I'm glad, but for *this* change thank ouah ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try `len-i` for the size of memory being moved. You definitely move memory that doesn't belong to you. (that said, I haven't really read the code).

Comment: Yes that was one of the bugs. Thank you