# Segmentation Fault ++operator on char *

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this Seg Fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638851/why-does-this-seg-fault)

I receive a segmentation fault when using ++ operator on a char *

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "hello";
    printf("%c ", ++(*s));
    return 0;
}
```

But if I do the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "hello";
    char c = *s;
    printf("%c ", ++c);
    return 0;
}
```

Then the code compiles perfectly, what is the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code snippet is attempting to modify a character in a string literal as:

```
++(*s)
```

is attempting to increment the first character in `s`. String literals are (commonly) read-only and an attempt to modify will cause the segmentation fault (the C standard states *If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*).

The second snippet is modifying a `char` variable, which is not read-only as after:

```
char c = *s;
```

`c` is a *copy* of the first character in `s` and `c` can be safely incremented.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you modify a constant literal, and in the second you modify a variable.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
printf("%c ", ++(*s));
```

tries to modify a string literal through a pointer to one of its characters. Modifying string literals is undefined behavior - the quite likely outcome is that string literals are often stored in read-only memory, so it's technically illegal to modify them and that's why it manifests itself as segmentation fault on your system.

Answer (score 1):

char *s = "hello";

This implies that 's' is a const string.

If you need a non-const string, you should allocate it explicitly from heap.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change a string literal in the first case which is not allowed. In the second case you create a new char from the first character of the string literal. You modify the copy of that character and that is why the second case works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have write permission for the segment where the string literal is stored.