# Why is this wrong?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this Seg Fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638851/why-does-this-seg-fault)
>   [What is the difference between char a[] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Trying to understand why s[0]='H' fails. I'm guessing this has something to do with the data segment in the process memory but maybe someone better explain this?

```
void str2 (void) 
{ 
    char *s = "hello"; 
    printf("%s\n", s); 
    s[0] = 'H';          //maybe this is a problem because content in s is constant? 
    printf("%s\n", s); 
}

int main()
{
    str2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. besides being a duplicate, your question title also would not be of much help to clarify what you are after.

Comment: What a nonsense question name !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's wrong because the C standard says that attempting to modify a string literal gives undefined behavior.

Exactly what will happen can and will vary. In some cases it'll "work" -- the content of the string literal will change to what you've asked (e.g., back in the MS-DOS days, it usually did). In other cases, the compiler will merge identical string literals, so something like:

```
char *a = "1234";
char *b = "1234";

a[1] = 'a';

printf("%s\n", b);
```

...would print out `1a34`, even though you never explicitly modified `b` at all.

In still other cases (including most modern systems) you can expect the attempted write to fail completely and some sort of exception/signal to be thrown instead.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I'm running this on windows and I got a "Application Crashed" message.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a string literal, which resides in implementation defined read only memory thereby causing an **Undefined Behavior**. Note that the undefined behavior does not warrant that your program crashes but it might show you any behavior.

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between char a[] = ?string?; and char *p = ?string?;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior, a good or stern compiler should not allow since this is (char *s = "hello") pointer to constant i.e. modifying the contents will lead to undefined behavior if the compiler will not throw any error on this